# Single sql query to select a record from parent table only if all it's records in child table has values

Tags: postgresql

I have above tables:
[image: In Which, T2.id1 is a foreign key from T1 and , T3.id1 and T3.id2 are foreign keys from T1 and T2]

I need a query to check if in T3, for each Id1 we have all Id2s according to T2, return result table above
in the table T2 there are only all id2 for id1 so in the result we just have All for id2 that is in the same row as id1 = 1 and Name3 is arrayed only in that row

Comment: Still unclear. `there are only all id2 for id1`? Meaning 11, 12 and 13 are the only possible values for `Id2`?  If all of them exist in T2 (or T3?) for the same `Id2`, we return an aggregated row with `Id2 = 'All'`, etc. From what I see, `T2` and `T3` can be merged to a single table. Start by providing actual table definitions showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres.

Comment: Are you going to clarify or can we close the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.Id1
     , CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT Id2) > 1 THEN 'All'::text
            ELSE min(Id2)::text END AS Id2
     , string_agg(DISTINCT Name3, ',') AS Name3
FROM        T2
LEFT   JOIN T3 USING (Id1, Id2)
GROUP  BY T2.Id1
HAVING bool_or(T3.Id1 IS NULL) IS FALSE;
```

Assuming all identifiers unquoted, so effectively case-insensitive.

Normally I add more explanation, but I'll match the silence in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry that my question was so silent I tried to add more explanation and rows to the tables to clarify my questions. Currently, count(DISTINCT Id2) > 1 doesn't work as I need.